# Magento Programmatically Save Store address

Tags: php, magento

I can be able to save store address programmatically by

```
$_address=nl2br('123\nTest',false);
$config->saveConfig('general/store_information/address',$_address,'default',0);
```

But the problem is `\n` are not converting into new lines even if I use `nl2br`.What could be the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using \n, \r or $someVar inside a php string, you need to use double quotes.

Try this:

```
$_address=nl2br("123\nTest",false);
```